# How to run javascript inside loading page that update the content without refreshing page. pls read details?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

This program is working perfectly it load `books.php` data into div. There is a javascript code inside the loading page `books.php` but this javascript not running. How can I solve this problem?

```
<button onclick='change("books.php")'> Books </button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

<script>
    function change(value) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#myDiv").load(value);
        });
    }

</script> 

</html>
```

Comment: My guess is that you are calling an event on an item that wasn't loaded in the DOM-structure, because you load in html after the webpage was already loaded.

Comment: how does the `books.php` look like?

Comment: "There is a javascript code inside" show that

Comment: i want to know only is it possible to run javascript inside loaded books.php ?

Answer (score 0):

move your JavaScript code from **books.php** to **separate** file and load it using

**$.getScript("js file url");**

Comment: i cannot see source code and data of loaded page books.php in browser source code window.